# Compile to a specific OpenMP version

Tags: gcc, openmp

I'm compiling a piece of C-code that uses OpenMP with GCC 5.4 (Ubuntu 16.04). The compiled code works fine when executed on the same machine and the OpenMP parts also works fine.

The problem is that I want to move the compiled binaries to a Centos 6.5 machine. Currently I get an error which says:

`/usr/lib64/libgomp.so.1: version 'GOMP_4.0' not found (required by ...)`

I understand that GCC 5.4 (which I compile my code with) supports OpenMP 4.0 but is there a way to force GCC5.4 to compile my code to a target which dosen't forces the OpenMP 4.0 support? The CentOS machine includes GCC4.3 (and thus OpenMP 3.0). Or is there another solution to my problem?

Comment: Why don't you just recompile on CentOS? Otherwise what about installing GCC4.3 on Ubuntu? Or maybe copy the Ubuntu `libgomp` runtime toe CentOS. I don't know if that will work.

Comment: What you can do, is compile your program with static linking. If that is possible in your case.

Comment: @Zboson It is difficult to just recomple on CentOS as I need other tools to actually get the C code which doesn't at the moment work on CentOS. For now  it would be messy to get it working so I was hoping for another solution.

Comment: @Qubit Thanks, I'll look into it. I've read though that it can lead to some issues if the OpenMP parts are linked in statically, any input on that? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't come across any issues doing so just yet, but I don't do it very often, so I suppose it's possible that you run into issues in some cases. If I were you, I'd just try, not much sense worrying about a problem that might not be there. Out of curiosity, could I have the link where you read this?

Comment: If you statically link an OpenMP runtime and then use a shared library which is also using OpenMP you can end up with two OpenMP runtimes in the same process. That potentially leads to oversubscription (since each runtime creates a thread pool)  and thus poor performance. I support @Z boson's idea of copying the runtime (or, at least, trying that!)